# Visualize time values over days in QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, timestamp, time-series, business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight

I have an event dataset in QuickSight, where each record has a timestamp field as following:

```
last_day_record_ts |
-------------------|
2020-01-19 05:46:55|
2020-01-20 05:55:37|
2020-01-21 06:00:12|
2020-01-22 06:12:57|
2020-01-23 06:02:15|
2020-01-24 06:15:35|
2020-01-25 06:20:05|
2020-01-26 05:55:48|
```

I want to build a visualization of **time values** over days as a line chart as following:
[image: The desired time values visualization]

However, I find it difficult to get this in AWS QuickSight. Any ideas?

Instead of desired result QuickSight persistently gives just aggregated record values (i.e 1 for each day) but not the time values itself...

**UPDATE**. The workaround I found for now - to add calculated fields to the Data Set in order to get numeric values instead of timestamp ones.

Calculated fields:

```
day_midnight            | truncDate('DD',{last_day_record_ts})
time_diff_in_hours_dec  | abs(dateDiff({last_day_record_ts},{day_midnight},"MI")) / 60
time_diff_in_hours_int  | decimalToInt({time_diff_in_hours_dec})
time_diff_in_min        | ({time_diff_in_hours_dec} - {time_diff_in_hours_int}) * 60
```

The only problem I still cannot solve - to get Y axis labels in HH:MM format as in green rectangle. For now, it's numeric decimals...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, (after many attempts of my own) this type of visual does not appear to be possible in [Quicksight](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-date-formats.html) at the time of writing.

Quicksight has many nice features, but it's still missing some (very basic imo) things that make it limiting for anyone working with data that is outside the expected use-cases.